# WiFi Access Point in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, hot-spot, hostapd

I know that this question had been asked several times on this site, but I couldn't find answers for my problem.

I want to create "Access Point" on my Ubuntu 12.04-LTS and share it with my Android phone.
I tried the methodes mentioned in these links but without success
[Link1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2009381) and [Link2](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-laptop-android/)

Here is what I have tried so far:

- I checked my wireless card capabilities with command `iw list` and the result contains "AP".
- I tried the two methods mentioned above and they worked fine with me, but for the first time only. Once I restart the computer, the script gives

  ```
  dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use [fail]
  ```
- When this error shows, my phone could see the access point but couldn't acquire IP address from the DHCP server.
- Then, I kill the dnsmasq and hostapd processes and restart the script.
- Now, I can aquire an IP-address from the computer but couldn't browse internet.

I know that I have overlooked something, but I can't figure it out.